# weight for max height in android when using wrap content?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two recycler views in my layout,
I want the second rv to have max height 40%, otherwise height should be wrap content.

```xml
<LinearLayout> <!-- vertical -->
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/> <!-- fill the height -->
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/> <!-- wrap the height, max: 40% -->
</LinearLayout>
```

This is something I want to achieve but don't know how?

Comment: if 2nd recycerview has data inn it so it should be 40% otherwise wrap_content with no data?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf wrap content if the height takes less than 40%...

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with a constraint layout. In Constraint layout Guideline view is used for implementing %.

here is an example for your use case

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.60"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In this first recycler view will take exact 60% of the screen and second will automatically take 40% of the screen.

Comment: But it fixes the first rv at 60%, it should fill the available height...

Comment: then you can just remove the dependency of the first RV from the guideline. Then only the second will be for 40%. And you can fill the whole screen with the first RV or do something else with it. It would be a lot easier if you can show the exact design you want to achieve.